# Snakemake : subworkflow not playing well with the main DAG

Tags: snakemake

I have a main Snakefile and several subworkflows running in independent subdirectories (with paths relative to their own directories). I've noticed that if I modify one of the input of a subworkflow, it will rerun correctly but all the following rules that come afterwards are not rerun.

If I understand correctly what is going on, there's a different DAG for the main Snakefile and for each subworkflow. The main DAG is not aware of any modification in a subworkflow and therefore won't trigger a rerun since the output of the subworkflow hasn't been modified yet.

I'd like that all the rules depending of the output of a subworkflow are rerun if there's a modification in that subworkflow. Isn't that what the default behaviour should be ?

I've also tried the other modularisation techniques. Using includes works but is super annoying because I have to modify all the paths to be relative to the main directory (and therefore I can't run snakemake independently in one subdirectory anymore). I've also tried using the new module system coming with snakemake v.6 that is supposed to be replacing subworkflows. Maybe I don't use it correctly, but it doesn't seem to work for my use case. If I import a rule from a subdirectory it complains that there are missing inputs. It doesn't find the scripts because they are in the subdirectory and not in the main directory. So in that sense it works more like an include than a subworkflow.

Do you have any idea on how to solve my issue ?

Here's a small working example with the module implementation:

MainDirectory
| - Snakefile

```
rule all:
    input: "Subdirectory/file.txt"

module other_workflow:
    snakefile: "Subdirectory/Snakefile"

use rule * from other_workflow as other_*
```

| - Subdirectory
| | - Snakefile

```
rule rule_a:
    input:
        script = 'code.py'
    output: 'file.txt'
    shell: 'python {input.script}'
```

| | - code.py

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('This is a test.', file=f)
```

This doesn't work as the snakefile in the main directory uses all the rules in the same workdir, whereas I would like it to be running the imported rules in their own workdir. I can make it work by modifying all the relative paths in the subdirectory but that's not what I want. I want to be able to run it without modifications.

Comment: I suggest to try the latest Snakemake release, which contains several fixes of initial bugs in the new module system, which indeed is meant to solve your use case.

Comment: If that still does not help, you can post a minimal example of your module based approach here and we can try to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @JohannesKöster, but it still doesn't work with version 6.1.1. I've added a minimal example. Let me know if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you mix input files with code here. If the script `code.py` is defined as an input file, Snakemake expects it to be in the workdir. If you'd use the [script directive](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#external-scripts) or the Jupyter notebook directive instead, the path will be automatically relative to the Snakefile. If that should be not an option for whatever reason, you can instead build the path relative to the current Snakefile via `Path(workflow.snakefile).parent / "code.py"`.

Note, there is really no reason to register code as input files. If you intend to get a rerun upon changes in the code, it is better to rely on `snakemake --list-code-changes`. The reason Snakemake does not automatically trigger reruns upon code changes is that they can be just cosmetic (e.g. formatting). Hence, it is up to the dev to trigger the rerun, e.g. via --list-code-changes, or manually.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about the script directive. The tutorial I followed was intentionally putting the scripts as input in order to trigger a rerun on code change. But this seems like a better solution. 
However, I still have a problem with my example above. The rule_a is now : 
`rule rule_a: output: 'file.txt' script: 'code.py'` (sorry I can't make a code block here) I want this rule to always produce the output file in the Subdirectory, while if I import this rule in the main snakefile, it will create it in the main directory. Is there no way to run the imported rule in its own directory ?

Comment: The script will run in the working directory of the Snakemake workflow. The place where you invoke the Snakemake command (or the place you define with --directory). You are free to create and store files and directories from the script by using any Python code. Regarding tutorials, I strongly suggest to do the official one which introduces into all necessary concepts and functionalities: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: I agree, but my point is that I would like the python code to create its output files in the subdirectory both when I run snakemake in the subdirectory and when I run it in the main directory. This is the behaviour that I get with subworkflows, but then the subworkflows are not integrated in the same DAG as the main snakefile which creates problems further down the chain. With modules everything is in the same DAG but then everything runs in the workdir of the main snakefile. Is there a solution to have both features at the same time ?

Comment: You can simply have a leading directory in the output file definition, say `mydirectory/file.txt` for the part that shall be in the subdirectory (or a hierarchy thereof).

Comment: It is also possible to change the output directories for modules globally, via specifying replacements for prefixes. Unfortunately, that is not yet explained in the docs, but you can find examples in the announcement slides: https://slides.com/johanneskoester/snakemake-6

Comment: Well, using `Subdirectory/file.txt` doesn't work if I run snakemake inside `Subdirectory`, that's exactly my problem.
And I've looked into the replacement of the prefixes, but what I would need in my example above is something like `replace_prefix: { "": "Subdirectory/"}`. That doesn't seem to work.